# default active field used for an anonymous union in c++

Tags: c++, c++17, g++, unions

Say I have something like this:

```
 struct a_struct
 {
      int number = 0;
 
      union
      {
           long l;
           short* sp;
      };
 };
```

And then, somewhere else in code, I declare an instance of the struct like

```
 a_struct temp;
 temp.number = -1;
```

Which would be the active field in the anonymous union?

Comment: Have you checked if [this code would compile](https://godbolt.org/z/aEbM9Kceb)?

Comment: If you have a type with a non-trivial default constructor (such as `std::string`) in your union, then you need to define a default constructor for it manually that chooses the active member. Otherwise the default constructor is deleted and `a_struct temp;` simply won't compile. (And same for other special member functions. E.g. the destructor of `std::string` is also non-trivial, so you need to define a destructor for the union yourself. Otherwise defining a variable won't work either.)

Comment: @DrewDormann fixed my example, sorry

Comment: @user17732522 i changed my code to remove the string. same question applies

Comment: Leaving out the string, I'm not sure you're much better off. If you don't initialize the value, you're setting yourself up for UB if you try to access the active member, whatever it is.

Comment: @user4581301 i was concerned that was the case.

Answer (score 2):

No member is initialized in an anonymous union by-default and so no subobject has its lifetime started and no member is set active. You'll have to set one active explicitly by assignment (where allowed), by new-expression, in `a_struct`'s constructor's member initializer list, or by adding a default member initializer to exactly one of the anonymous union members.

Even if one were automatically active, it would still need to be assigned a value before reading from it. The members of the anonymous union need to have trivial default constructors in order for your example to be well-formed at all, so they will have indeterminate values in all their scalar subobjects after default-initialization and reading an indeterminate value causes undefined behavior (with some very minor exceptions).